# R: Average length of period

Tags: r

This is sample data:

```
x1       x2
3.2      3.2
NA       3.2
NA       3.2
4.1      4.1
NA       4.1
2.6      2.6
NA       2.6
NA       2.6  
4.1      4.1
NA       4.1
NA       4.1
NA       4.1
3.0      3.0
NA       3.0
3.0      3.0
NA       3.0
NA       3.0
NA       3.0
```

The data has an index of the ideological composition of the government from 1 to 5 (left to right in political sense). x1 in the sample data is the first month of the new government and the index value for it, and x2 is just the same value for each month that government has been in power. I need to find out the mean (or median and other statistics) length or the government term. The thing is that the index values might be the same, so I cannot use that value as e.g. the index for tapply or such. So I would need to get the length of the period with same values to a vector preferably. Any ideas?

Edit: It happens to be that there is one case in the data where the two consecutive terms have the same value, added that to the end of the sample data.

Comment: You question is not complete clear to me. Do you want to figure out the length of equal values? E.g. `rle(x2)$lengths`?

Comment: it would be clearer if your example contained two terms that share the same value. It will show that the simple use of rle fails

Comment: @amit Good point. It just so happens to be that there is one case in the data where two consecutive terms have the same value.

Comment: @sgibb Yes, now that you mention rle, I want to figure out the lengths of the consecutive runs, BUT there is a case in the data where two consecutive runs have the same index value essentially looking like one run even though there are two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
term.lengths = diff(which(!is.na(c(x1,length(x1)+1))))
mean(term.lengths)
median(term.lengths)
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would use `cumsum(!is.na(x1))`:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
x1       x2
3.2      3.2
NA       3.2
NA       3.2
4.1      4.1
NA       4.1
2.6      2.6
NA       2.6
NA       2.6
4.1      4.1
NA       4.1
NA       4.1
NA       4.1
3.0      3.0
NA       3.0
3.0      3.0
NA       3.0
NA       3.0
NA       3.0"), header=TRUE)

gterms <- cumsum(!is.na(df$x1))
#  [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 6 6

tapply(df$x2, gterms, mean)
#   1   2   3   4   5   6 
# 3.2 4.1 2.6 4.1 3.0 3.0
```